# Pandas select Rows with the same time

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe like this:

```
                      X      Y
1999-09-05 09:00:00 15.4    1.0
1999-09-05 11:00:00 18.1    0.0
1999-09-05 12:00:00 18.8    1.0
1999-09-05 13:00:00 19.3    0.0
1999-09-05 14:00:00 18.8    0.0
....
```

The dataframe has a X and a Y column for every Hour of a day.

I want extra dataframes for every Hour of a day

Like this:

df 01:00

```
1999-09-05 01:00:00 13.4    1.0
1999-09-06 01:00:00 13.8    1.0
1999-09-07 01:00:00 15.4    1.0
```

...

df 23:00

```
1999-09-05 23:00:00 13.4    1.0
1999-09-06 23:00:00 13.8    1.0
1999-09-07 23:00:00 15.4    1.0
```

I tried to use the df.loc function but i failed.

```
  df.loc[df.index == '08:00:00']
```

Another way to solve my problem would be:

How can i filter just the time in dataframes?

Like i want to calculate .mean() for every row with the time 08:00 in the index

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming your data is in `df` and the `datetime` column is the index,

You can use `df.loc[df.index.to_series().dt.hour == 8]`

Comment: And how can i just locate one Column and not the whole DF with the given index? @akilat90

Comment: @Meiiso `df.loc[df.index.to_series().dt.hour > 8, "<COLUMN NAME>"]`